# SMS sent report INSIDE broadcastReceiver in Android

Tags: android

In my app I need to send SMS from BraodCast Receiver class and based on the sent sms report I need to notify the the app. I found many example but all is calling sent sms from activity class but not Broadcast Receiver class. I even created a private function but got error on registerReceiver.
Please help me out. I have already sent many days searching for the solution.

my private function I created in BroadcastReceiver is
    private int sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message,
            final Context context) {
        String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
        String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";
        int smsSuccess = 0;

```
    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
            new Intent(SENT), 0);

    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
            new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

    // ---when the SMS has been sent---
    context.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode()) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                isSent = 1;
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                isSent = 0;
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                isSent = 0;
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                isSent = 0;
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                isSent = 0;
                break;
            }
        }

    }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

    // ---when the SMS has been delivered---
    context.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode()) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                isReceived = 1;
                break;
            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                isReceived = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);

    if (isSent == 1 && isReceived == 1) {
        smsSuccess = 1;
        return smsSuccess;
    } else {
        return smsSuccess;
    }
}
```

and the error I got is

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-09 17:24:10.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2168): Process:  PID: 2168
01-09 17:24:10.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2168): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver easyApp.NotificationReceiver: android.content.ReceiverCallNotAllowedException: BroadcastReceiver components are not allowed to register to receive intents
01-09 17:24:10.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2168):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2407)
01-09 17:24:10.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2168):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:135)
01-09 17:24:10.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2168):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
01-09 17:24:10.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2168):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-09 17:24:10.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2168):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-09 17:24:10.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2168):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
01-09 17:24:10.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2168):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-09 17:24:10.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2168):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-09 17:24:10.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2168):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
01-09 17:24:10.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2168):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
01-09 17:24:10.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2168):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-09 17:24:10.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2168): Caused by: android.content.ReceiverCallNotAllowedException: BroadcastReceiver components are not allowed to register to receive intents
01-09 17:24:10.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2168):     at android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:148)
01-09 17:24:10.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2168):     at android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:137)
01-09 17:24:10.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2168):     at easyApp.geniemail.NotificationReceiver.sendSMS(NotificationReceiver.java:332)
01-09 17:24:10.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2168):     at easyApp.geniemail.NotificationReceiver.onReceive(NotificationReceiver.java:220)
01-09 17:24:10.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2168):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2400)
01-09 17:24:10.778: E/AndroidRuntime(2168):     ... 10 more

Comment: The error log  is pretty straight forward I should say. "BroadcastReceiver components are not allowed to register to receive intents".

Comment: Remove the `registerReceiver()` calls and switch to manifest-registered receivers.

Comment: Can you please give me some example? I don't know how to switch to manifest-registered receiver.

Comment: anyone who can help me. I am still waiting to get any solution to my problem.